# Why does memset print different value when it's set to non zero?

Tags: arrays, c, memset

I am trying to understand `memset` and pointer to an array. Below is my program and when I set the array contents 0 the value of `*(p+6)` prints 0.
But when I set the value to 5 `*(p+6)` it prints `84215045`

Not sure whats going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int *p;
int dtk[0xA0];

int main()
{
    memset (dtk, 0, 160*sizeof(dtk[0]));
    p = dtk;
    printf("dtk,%d",*(p+6));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: heres a clue `84215045` in hex is `0x05050505`

Comment: change value to char and  change print format with %c. Example : memset (dtk, '5', 0x0A); and printf("dtk,%c",*(p+6));  the output is '5'

Answer (score 1):

As Raymond Chen alluded, each byte in the 32-bit int is being set to 5, with the result being `(5<<24) + (5<<16) + (5<<8) + 5 == 84215045`.